# ¿Cómo se realiza el mantenimiento de SO?

Tags: soporte, stackexchange

En general tengo esta duda sobre qué procesos atraviesa Stack Overflow para darle mantenimiento al sitio o incluir nuevas funcionalidades.

## ¿Quiénes son los "encargados" de realizar estas acciones?

Por lo que **creo** saber esta tarea la realizan algunos moderadores o miembros antiguos de la comunidad, que sin ánimo de lucro han contribuido en el código fuente para mejorar las herramientas y calidad del sitio.

## ¿Cómo eligen a esas personas?

No todas las personas tienen el conocimiento o la habilidad para realizar cambios sobre un proyecto tan grande como me imagino que es esta comunidad, por tanto, me pregunto qué restricciones hay para sugerir cambios, implementaciones o mejoras.

## ¿Quién o quiénes aprueban esas modificaciones?

Como no toda contribución puede aceptarse, ¿Cuáles son los criterios que se usan para discriminar o aceptar cambios?, ¿Cómo se hacen las pruebas del software?, ¿Qué se hace en caso de que un cambio al sistema en ejecución resulte perjudicial?

Lamento incluir tantas preguntas en una sola, pero me surgieron bastantes dudas al leer en varias publicaciones en META que realizar cambios incluso a un artículo no es para nada sencillo.

Comment: veo sin sentido los votos negativos en esta pregunta, sinceramente a todos les vendría bien saber un poco como funciona la estructura de SO. ya que solo conocemos que todos somos usuarios; creo que alguien nuevo se le hace difícil identificar un moderador o un empleado hasta que a uno de ellos les salga presentarse... incluso este link: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges me parece que deberia estar en el perfil; pero nunca lo he encontrado, hay que irse a la ayuda...

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso El botón de privilegios siempre esta a la vista... solo que en un botón combinado, logros recientes, lo que seria, logros, reputación, y medallas. Solo son 2 clicks desde muchos lados.

Comment: Tienes un Mal concepto de lo que hacen los usuarios antiguos y Moderadores.

Comment: El contenido de cada sitio (Post, Comentarios, Wikies) es la parte publica; aquí es donde los Usuarios dedican tiempo a evaluar cada preguntar, agregar respuestas y evaluarlas (dan Mantenimiento al Contenido) no hacen cambios en funcionalidades del sitio.

Comment: Dependiendo de la reputación (puntos) los usuarios van ganando privilegios que otorga permisos para dar Mantenimiento a las preguntas y respuestas. tambien tenemos a los Moderadores, que son Usuarios con "Super Poderes" que les ha otorgado la Comunidad al elegirlos para el cargo, sin Requerir que hayan alcanzado todos los privilegios por puntaje.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/company) es una empresa privada.

El código fuente de como funciona el sitio, es propietario de la empresa y tanto los usuarios como los moderadores no tienen acceso al mismo.

Algunos usuarios han construido herramientas externas que ayudan al mantenimiento del sitio. Aunque estos proyectos en muchos casos estan avalados totalmente por la compañia, e incluso ayudan con determinadas cosas en los mismos, es la comunidad quien mantiene los mismos. (los mas claros ejemplos son [SmokeDetector](https://charcoal-se.org) y [Traducir](https://traducir.win)).

No hay personas que no pertenezcan a la empresa que modifiquen el codigo fuente de la pagina. El codigo fuente no es publico. Si es publico el esquema de la base de datos y se puede acceder a la misma para hacer consultas utilizando una herramienta provista por la compañia que se llama [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com).

Los moderadores electos, ayudan con la limpieza del sitio en cuanto a preguntas, usuarios y otros temas menores, pero solo ayudan con la "vista" del sitio. Tiene permiso para modificar algunas cosas (como por ejemplo los motivos de cierre), pero solo pueden modificar cosas de "vista".

Los CM de la compañía son quienes tienen acceso a las partes privadas e interactúan con los moderadores cuando necesitan ayuda para modificar cosas que están dentro del código (por ejemplo, las paginas de ayuda).

Las traducciones del sitio están en un lugar publico (transifex), y cualquier usuario puede ayudar con las mismas, aunque ahora usemos exclusivamente traducir.